# Select count of same column with different value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Status] AS Requested
    ,[Status] AS [Sent]
    ,[Status] AS Finished
     FROM Store.[Order]
```

`Status` is an int value and I want Count all Status

1. Count value = 1 and display as a Requested.
2. Count value = 2 and display as Sent.
3. Count value = 3 and display as Finished.

How can I achieve it? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` expression to count status based on value (*1,2,3*)

```
SELECT 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Requested,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Finished
FROM Store.[Order]
```